# Getting Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.ajax.onload

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, ajaxform

I want to pass this using ajax to controller but getting this error. Console log for the responseText and get html code. Trying to figure out what does this mean?

Javascript:

```
    // gathering the form data
                var ajaxData = new FormData( form );

                if( droppedFiles )
                {
                    Array.prototype.forEach.call( droppedFiles, function( file )
                    {
                        ajaxData.append( input.getAttribute( 'name' ), file );
                    });
                }
                
                console.log(ajaxData);
                // ajax request
                var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                ajax.open( form.getAttribute( 'method' ), form.getAttribute( 'action' ), true );
                ajax.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
                ajax.onload = function()
                {
                    form.classList.remove( 'is-uploading' );
                    if( ajax.status >= 200 && ajax.status < 400 )
                    {
                        var data = JSON.parse( ajax.responseText );
                        form.classList.add( data.success == true ? 'is-success' : 'is-error' );
                        if( !data.success ) errorMsg.textContent = data.error;
                    }
                    else alert( 'Error. Please, contact the webmaster!' );
                };

                ajax.onerror = function()
                {
                    form.classList.remove( 'is-uploading' );
                    alert( 'Error. Please, try again!' );
                };

                ajax.send( ajaxData );
```

Index

```
<form method="post" action="/contacts/{{$groupContactDetails->id}}/importContacts" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate class="box">
        <div class="box__input">
        <input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" class="box__file d-none" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
        <label for="file"><strong>Choose a file</strong><span class="box__dragndrop"> or drag it here</span>.</label>
        <button type="submit" class="box__button btn btn-info">Upload</button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: This is a general error like "Null pointer" - it's often happening, not only in Laravel, but usually with AJAX (error from JSON.parse) - probably you've got HTML from the server (which often starts with "<"), go to the browser developer tools (F12, Ctrl+Shift+C) -> Network and see what the request actually returned. Often you'll find an error page (in HTML).

Answer (score 0):

You are having malformed or non-json response from the server. You need to check the response data to be sure you are receiving data in JSON form.

One way you can do this:

```js
    ajax.onload = function()
                {
                    form.classList.remove( 'is-uploading' );
                    if( ajax.status >= 200 && ajax.status < 400 )
                    {   
                         try {
                               var data = JSON.parse( ajax.responseText );
                              form.classList.add( data.success == true ? 'is-success' : 'is-error' );
                          } catch (e) {
                             console.log( ajax.responseText);
                            //data isn't json type, do error handling here
                         }
                        if( !data.success ) errorMsg.textContent = data.error;
                    }
                    else alert( 'Error. Please, contact the webmaster!' );
                };
```

Comment: @LeviLooi your error lies in the data that your are trying to JSON.parse, if it's not valid then the error is caught and the data is logged to console. What's the data that's logged?

Comment: That's your issue, you can only parse JSON data via JSON.parse, for html data, you don't need JSON.parse, use the data directly